# Graphic - Edge Effect animation (automatic)

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-progressbar, android-drawable

I have wonderful image from my Graphic but there is a problem with the "LED EFFECT".

The problem is with-in white square - i would to have this as in the effect Edge Effect.

Edge Effect is inside Android - I have found a way to make it bigger and better but still it need UI interaction to activate.

[image]

1) How to make it into layout - what type will be the best ?
2) How to make Edge Effect as animation - when i press button it will activate and go from MIN to MAX value (preferred would be on start as animation) 
3) If i load the color from file - how to make it in Code that will automatically change the it

Bouns Question : This Edge Effect was putted to ver 3.0 + . Will it be working on 2.3.3 ?

Sorry but I am a N00b in this matters (English is also not used often :))